# Autoware - Vehicle Interface Documentation?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning on implementing a vehicle interface to allow Autoware to control a vehicle my university owns. Based on the diagram from: https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/pull/1945  it looks like the Autoware autonomy will publish an autoware_msgs/VehicleCmd and expect an autoware_msgs/VehicleStatus. But I can't find any definition of what is the expected behavior of the interface. For example, if the variable int32 emergency in autoware_msgs/VehicleCmd is set to something (don't even know the values it should take) what should be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336000/autoware---vehicle-interface-documentation?/) by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2019-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swsllc](https://answers.ros.org/users/48369/swsllc/) on 2019-10-30**:
Has the safety of this implementation been assessed?

**Comment by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on 2019-10-30**:
Considering it will be a non-commercial limited use case implementation, I doubt we will assess the safety of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@patrick-n This is mostly up to the vehicle interface developer. The idea behind the generic `autoware_msgs/VehicleCmd` message is to provide several options for how the vehicle can be controlled and each drive-by-wire interface developer will handle the information provided in a different way. Unfortunately, there is currently no "developer guide" for compatibility of drive-by-wire systems with Autoware.ai.

Regarding the components of VehicleCmd, they are combined by the `twist_gate` node from several input topics:

The `accel_cmd`, `brake_cmd`, `steer_cmd`, `gear_cmd`, `mode_cmd`, and `lamp_cmd` values are populated by individual topics (named the same as the value names) which are published by upstream components. These comprise one method of vehicle control.

`ctrl_cmd` contains `linear_acceleration`, `linear_velocity` and `steering_angle` properties. This is another method of vehicle control.

`twist_cmd` contains a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message which, in turn, contains linear and angular components. This is another method of control.

Depending upon which components are enabled upstream and which options are set on them, different portions of this message will be populated. The typical methodology for how to handle this is either:

1. Decide that you will only support one control method and inform your users.
2. Listen to all components but create a priority order within your interface.

I'm sorry this isn't more straightforward but this is one of the tasks that the Autoware Vehicle Interface Working Group is trying to tackle. Please let me know if you have further questions.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on 2019-10-31**:
Thanks for the response. Do you know which package is most used for sending commands in Autoware?